# urls do not show up in in biblatex-mla Works Cited list

Tags: biblatex, urls, mla-style

Using the texlive distribution on Arch Linux.  I have:

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla]{biblatex}
\bibliography{sources.bib}
...
```

In sources.bib I have:

```
@article{taylor,
%...
howpublished = {Web},
url = {http://www.etc.com/blah/blah/blah}
}
```

Everything shows up except the url.  I've also tried putting `\usepackage{url}` in the preamble and changing the url line to `url = {\url{http://www.etc.com/blah/blah/blah}}` and it makes no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The newest edition of the MLA Handbook recommends against showing the URL. If you'd like to go against these recommendations and use something close to the previous edition, add the package option `showmedium=false` to the preamble:

```
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=mla,showmedium=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{sources.bib}
```

Watch out, though, as this option attempts to retain previous stylings without making any promises. In your example, among other things, both "Web" and the period following it will be missing.

One nice thing to keep in mind about the default usage: URLs for eprint sources, while always being hidden from print, still nevertheless supercharge the PDF. Check out the following Bibtex entry as an example:

```
@article{barrowsaa,    
    Author = {Adam Barrows},    
    Eprint = {http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/modern_fiction_studies/v056/56.2.barrows.html},    
    Eprinttype = {muse},    
    Issue = {Summer},    
    Journal = {Modern Fiction Studies},    
    Number = {2},    
    Pages = {262--289},    
    Title = {`The Shortcomings of Timetables': Greenwich, Modernism, and the Limits of Modernity.},    
    Url = {http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/modern_fiction_studies/v056/56.2.barrows.html},    
    Urldate = {2011-02-17},    
    Volume = {56},    
    Year = {2010}}
```

Here's the resulting text, with the database text (Project Muse) functioning as a hyperlink to the article:

> Barrows, Adam. “‘The Shortcomings of Timetables’: Greenwich, Modernism, and the 
>   Limits of Modernity.” *Modern Fiction Studies* 56.2 (Summer 2010): 
>   262–289. *[Project Muse](http://muse.jhu.edu/journals/modern_fiction_studies/v056/56.2.barrows.html)*. Web. 17 Feb. 2011.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realised the latest MLA recommendation was not to show the URL.  I thought I was doing something wrong in my .tex or .bib files.

Comment: Well the option remains per publisher still to show it. (There are always caveats, tradeoffs, and qualifications.) It makes sense to me to make options to print the URL at the end of the entry, so I'll see about adding it in an upcoming release.

Comment: Thanks for this post, now I don’t need to search around any longer. I would heartly welcome an option to toggle url + also access date visibility apart from the settings of the latest style guide edition since it seems odd to quote for instance a video from youtube w/o pointing the reader to the URL. Best, Jakob PS: Sorry for posting this as another answer, I meant it to be a comment.

Comment: Jakob, it seems the best option would include a modification of the @video entrytype that supports a URL. I'll add that to my list of issues for an upcoming release.

Answer (score 2):

I've moved `biblatex-MLA` development to [GitHub](https://github.com/jmclawson/biblatex-mla/tree/dev).

In this development branch, I've added support for an `@online` entrytype, and I've added support for the `noremoteinfo` package option, which defaults to `true`. By setting `noremoteinfo=false` as a package option when you load `biblatex`, the URL will be printed at the end of each entry. (Whether or not you set that option, the word "Web" will now also serve as a link in the PDF to the URL using `hyperref`.)

Comment: Thank for adding this functionality! Do you think you could update this answer (including the link) since the option has moved to the release branch?