# Biblatex mla - no bibliography, no references, no nothing

Tags: biblatex, biber, mla-style, bibdesk

I'm relatively new to the world of LaTeX, but so far I managed to put together a nice looking layout by browsing through StackExchange and reading manuals. Now I've been trying for 3 days to get things working. It's time to ask the pro's.

I've prepared a minimal example because I can't get `biber` and `biblatex` working. I get 12 warnings in my log when compiling my PDF.

All because of my cites and footnotes don't translate well. I boils done to a `undefined control sequence` problem: `\citet` and `\citep` don't get me anywhere with biblatex. This (full log [here](http://pastebin.com/NKLDJ7Y7)):

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'McGrane:2014' on page 1 undefined on input line 68.

Package biblatex Warning: '\textcite' not defined by citation style.
(biblatex)                Falling back to '\cite' on input line 68.

LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 92.

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                min-biblatex
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Of course my references don't get converted they look like the cite-key from BibDesk `(Basich:2003)` and… my bibliography doesn't get printed, too :/

Aside from using Sublime Text for building the PDF I also tried the commandline with `pdflatex min-biblatex`, `biber min-biblatex`, `pdflatex min-biblatex`, `pdflatex min-biblatex` and as last resort TeXShop, too.

**(Almost)MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half-,a4paper,twoside=false,bibliography=totocnumbered,version=first,listof=numbered,numbers=noenddot,version=first]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
% ENCODING & TRANSLATION
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{utf8}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% BIBLIOGRAPHY & CITATION
\usepackage{hyperref}
%   ::BIBLIOGRAPHY::
\usepackage[natbib=true,
            backref=true,
            hyperref=true,
            showmedium=false,
            % autocite=footnote,
            % firstinits=true,
            % indexing=true,
            url=true,           %
            style=mla,          %  style=debug, alphabetic
            backend=biber,      %
            % doi=false,
            texencoding=utf8,
            bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8)
@webpage{McGrane:2014,
    Author = {Sally McGrane},
    Day = {17},
    Lastchecked = {2014-03-23},
    Month = {February},
    Note = {Last checked: 2014-03-23},
    Publisher = {The New Yorker},
    Title = {To the Magic Mountain!},
    Url = {http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/to-the-magic-mountain},
    Year = {2014}}

@webpage{ThomasMannArchiv,
    Lastchecked = {2014-06-18},
    Publisher = {Thomas-Mann-Archiv},
    Title = {Das Internationale Sanatorium »Berghof«},
    Url = {http://www.tma.ethz.ch/assets/Uploads/Ueber-uns/Thomas-Sprecher/Dokumente/4.-Das-Internationale-Sanatorium-Berghof.pdf}}

@book{Mann:1924,
    Address = {Frankfurt am Main},
    Author = {Thomas Mann},
    Edition = {Gro{\ss}e kommentierte Frankfurter Ausgabe, Band 5.1},
    Editor = {Michael Neumann},
    Publisher = {S. Fischer},
    Title = {Der Zauberberg},
    Year = {2010}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Cites and Footnotes}
\label{citesandfootnotes}

Footnote 1\footnote{~\citep{Anderson:1999}} and 2\footnote{~\citep[S. 23f]{Monagas:2007}}. Inline cites [e.g.][p. 2]~\citep{Sprecher:2002} and ~\citep[p 66f]{Basich:2003}. Three cites: author v1~\citep{McGrane:2014}, v2 \citet{Mann:1924} and a quote from  \citet{ThomasMannArchiv}:

\begin{quote}

This is a quote.
\end{quote}

\section{Pics and Tables}
\label{picsandtables}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{A diagram}
\label{dia1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{A table}
\label{table_tab}
\end{figure}

%end of text
\pagebreak
\appendix
\begingroup
\printbibliography
\listoffigures
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I also cleaned the cache via `` rm -rf `biber --cache `` since I read that `biber` is prone to malfunction because of it.

---

**Setup**

- I use [BibDesk](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/) to manage my references.
- I have the latest [MacTeX](http://www.tug.org/mactex/whatsinthepackage.html) bundle installed (TeXShop, TeXworks, biber, etc.) which leaves me at `biber` 1.8 with the fitting `biblatex` package.
- I write in MultiMarkdown and let [Scrivener](http://www.literatureandlatte.com/scrivener.php) convert my text to LaTeX. This also means that my LaTeX content will always look like what you see after `\begin{document}`.
- I compile with [Sublime Text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) and the [LaTeX-Plus](https://github.com/randy3k/LaTeX-Plus) package (which uses `latexmk`). Sometimes I also use TeXShop.

---

**Before `biblatex` there was `natbib`**

I used to use `natbib` where everything almost worked, too. Despite these five issues:

1. No support for `[e.g.][p. 333]~\citep{author-key}`
2. Can't get `lastchecked` (aka date accessed) field from BibDesk to show up in the bibliography. Dissatisfying workaround: use the `note field` in BibDesk.
3. Inline cites still show up in `apacite` format *(author, year, page)* instead of mla format *(author, page)*
4. Doesn't replace unknown author (aka with no author field) in inline citation with something useful.
5. `natbib` => not ideal for humanities

`apacite` style worked pretty well, but I needed `mla` – that's how I end up giving `biblatex` a shot.

For reference purposes the mla minimal example:

- [bst file](http://cl.ly/WjuR/mla-custom.bst)
- [minimal example](http://pastebin.com/Ep0irzz7)

---

Stuff I came across that didn't help me:

- [citing - Biblatex-nature \textcite with superscript reference number - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162309/biblatex-nature-textcite-with-superscript-reference-number)

  - This feels close but I don't really know if converting all entries to something biblatex/biber (?) understands is the solution or if there's an easier way out.
- [miktex - Biblatex, Biber pdflatex: undefined references - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134433/biblatex-biber-pdflatex-undefined-references)
- [Biblatex: \textcite style in footnotes - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172128/biblatex-textcite-style-in-footnotes)

Comment: I just read the error log "Package biblatex Warning: '\textcite' not defined by citation style." I don't know the mla-style. Maybe you should check, whether it defines citations and everything. A short view on the manual shows, that the author only speaks of `\autocite`. Maybe other cite-commands are not implemented.

Comment: also, the manual dates from May 2013. Could be outdated? http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-mla/doc/biblatex-mla.pdf

Comment: The `webpage` entry type is undefined, nor is there any such field. Four citations do not exist in  `literature.bib` as defined in you post. Apart from that, everything compiles fine with MiKTeX.

Comment: When citations are not resolved this is normally due to problems in the biber run. Show the blg-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I was able to solve that by adding `citestyle=authoryear`.

Comment: @musicman Sadly this is the state of things. You really have to dig through the Internet to find something more up to date. Some people have more recent complete packages for there special field. I've found a linguistics one that looks good, but is of no use to me.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for pointing this out. It was a mistake which shouldn't happen when posting something here (´。＿。｀).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @cfr and @Bernard pointed out I made some mistakes and submitted a version with missing bibliography entries *(==> never submit a StackExchange question when you're super-tired)*.

**Correction 1: I edited the MWE to have proper bib entries.**

---

I also switched my BibDesk setup to a confirm more with BibLateX – see [BibLateX Types and Fields](http://sourceforge.net/p/bibdesk/wiki/Tips_and_Tricks/#biblatex-types-and-fields) where you can [download a TypeInfo.plist](http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/TypeInfo_biblatex.plist) which has all the glitz and glam of BibLaTex.

**Correction 2: In addition to the above I switched from `@webpage` to `@online`.**

---

My syntax for using prenotes and postnotes was messed up. As stated in the initial question I use MultiMarkdown and let Scrivener convert my document to a `.tex` file.

**Correction 3: Here's the correct MMD syntax – note the two `\`.**

```
MMD =====> [see\]\[6][#Mann:1924]
LaTeX ===> ~\citep[see][6]{Mann:1924}
PDF =====> (see Mann, 1924, S. 6)
```

---

No type (i.e. "Web", "Print", etc.) was added to the bibliography. In addition, `Urldate` still gets printed *without* an automatic prefix like "Last checked/Access Date/Last accessed". *Automatic* is a must since I write in more than one language.

I guess problems like this don't occur if you don't rely on `natbib=true` and can just use plain `biblatex-mla` styles with `autocite` & Co. But that's an okay price to pay for writing in Markdown and Scrivener. Maybe some day I'm smart enough to use `renewcommand` to the max and transform my whole `natbib`-dependent output.

**Correction 4: Set `showmedium` to `true` so that the type of medium gets printed. This is mandatory when writing in MLA style.**

↑ This doesn't correct the missing prefix but can certainly be neglected now since the *published date* and the *date of the last access* are now divided by the *type of medium* which makes for a cleaner reading experience.

---

You might have noted that the bibliography sported a "(Siehe S. 1)" after every entry. It was unnecessary and without a purpose.

**Correction 5: Set `backref` to `false`.**

---

With MLA the correct format for cites is `(Author page)` without the comma.

**Correction 6: Add `\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}` to your preamble. It removes the comma in-between cites. To remove the additional info (p./S.) also add `\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}`.**

---

Here's the cleaned-up version with additional bug fixes to emulate all MLA necessary standards.

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half-,a4paper,twoside=false,bibliography=totocnumbered,version=first,listof=numbered,numbers=noenddot,version=first]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{utf8}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backref=false,
            natbib=true,
            hyperref=true,
            showmedium=true,
            autocite=footnote,
            url=true,
            style=mla,
            citestyle=authortitle-ticomp,
            sorting=nyvt,
            backend=biber,
            texencoding=utf8,
            maxnames=2,
            bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\postnotedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
@article{Anderson:1999,
    Author = {Anderson, Kirsten L.},
    Journal = {Journal of Sport and Social Issues},
    Pages = {55-79},
    Title = {Snowboarding: The Construction of Gender in an Emerging Sport},
    Type = {Journal},
    Volume = {23},
    Year = {1999}}
@online{McGrane:2014,
    Author = {McGrane, Sally},
    Day = {17},
    Month = {February},
    Publisher = {The New Yorker},
    Title = {To the Magic Mountain!},
    Url = {http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/to-the-magic-mountain},
    Urldate = {2014-03-23},
    Urlday = {23},
    Urlmonth = {March},
    Urlyear = {2014},
    Year = {2014}}
@book{Mann:1924,
    Author = {Mann, Thomas},
    Edition = {Gro{\ss}e kommentierte Frankfurter Ausgabe},
    Volumes = {5.1},
    Editor = {Neumann, Michael},
    Publisher = {S. Fischer GmbH},
    Rating = {5},
    Title = {Der Zauberberg},
    Location = {Frankfurt am Main},
    Note = {PDF Version},
    Year = {2010}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Footnotes, Cites and Quotes}
\label{citation}
First mention of primary literature\footfullcite[page 23]{Mann:1924}.

Postnote ~\citep[19]{Anderson:1999}.

Ibid test ~\citep[see][]{Anderson:1999} and ~\citep[see][762]{Anderson:1999}.

Inline prenote  \citet[see][]{Mann:1924}.

Pre-{} and postnote ~\citep[e.g.][99]{McGrane:2014}.

Prenote ~\citep[see][]{McGrane:2014}.

Just the key ~\citep{Anderson:1999}.

\begin{quote}

This is a quote.~\citep[984]{Mann:1924}
\end{quote}

Next section reference see \autoref{figures}

\chapter{Pics and Tables Demo}
\label{figures}

Test section reference \autoref{citation}


\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{A diagram~\citep{McGrane:2014}}
\label{dia1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\caption{A table~\citep[see][]{McGrane:2014}}
\label{table_tab}
\end{figure}

%end of text
\pagebreak
\appendix
\begingroup
\printbibliography
\listoffigures
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[**LIVE PREVIEW**](https://www.writelatex.com/read/ymbrkmybscqw)

---

**Note regarding correction 3 and 4:** I'm still running into (compatibility?) problems when authoring a PDF designed for digital consume (i.e. not for print). When I try to use the `eprint` and `eprinttype` fields

More in this post: [urls do not show up in in biblatex-mla Works Cited list - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29854/urls-do-not-show-up-in-in-biblatex-mla-works-cited-list)

If `showmedium` is off and all eprint parameters are set there are two URL outputs. Especially `urldate` is tricky since I could delete `URL` and just use `eprint` and `eprinttype` but then there would be the date duplication. Messy. I guess this is also a `natbib=true` issue.

PS: I also don't get how to format these: Do I always have to use `muse`… whatever… I have to google this. This last chapter is only here for reference purposes of fellow BibLaTex + natbib users.

Answer (score 2):

As Bernard says, it works except for the bits which don't work due to non-existent types, unrecognised fields or missing bibliography entries.

Rather than `webpage`, you may want `online`. Rather than `lastchecked`, you probably want `urldate`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,parskip=half-,a4paper,twoside=false,bibliography=totocnumbered,version=first,listof=numbered,numbers=noenddot,version=first]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
% ENCODING & TRANSLATION
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\inputencoding{utf8}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
% BIBLIOGRAPHY & CITATION
\usepackage{hyperref}
%   ::BIBLIOGRAPHY::
\usepackage[natbib=true,
            backref=true,
            hyperref=true,
            showmedium=false,
            % autocite=footnote,
            % firstinits=true,
            % indexing=true,
            url=true,           %
            style=mla,          %  style=debug, alphabetic
            backend=biber,      %
            % doi=false,
            texencoding=utf8,
            bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}

\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{literature.bib}
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8)
@online{McGrane:2014,
    Author = {Sally McGrane},
    Day = {17},
    urldate = {2014-03-23},
    Month = {February},
    Publisher = {The New Yorker},
    Title = {To the Magic Mountain!},
    Url = {http://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/to-the-magic-mountain},
    Year = {2014}}

@online{ThomasMannArchiv,
    urldate = {2014-06-18},
    Publisher = {Thomas-Mann-Archiv},
    Title = {Das Internationale Sanatorium »Berghof«},
    Url = {http://www.tma.ethz.ch/assets/Uploads/Ueber-uns/Thomas-Sprecher/Dokumente/4.-Das-Internationale-Sanatorium-Berghof.pdf}}

@book{Mann:1924,
    Address = {Frankfurt am Main},
    Author = {Thomas Mann},
    Edition = {Gro{\ss}e kommentierte Frankfurter Ausgabe, Band 5.1},
    Editor = {Michael Neumann},
    Publisher = {S.\ Fischer},
    Title = {Der Zauberberg},
    Year = {2010}}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Cites and Footnotes}
\label{citesandfootnotes}

Footnote 1\footnote{~\citep{Anderson:1999}} and 2\footnote{~\citep[S. 23f]{Monagas:2007}}. Inline cites [e.g.][p. 2]~\citep{Sprecher:2002} and ~\citep[p 66f]{Basich:2003}. Three cites: author v1~\citep{McGrane:2014}, v2 \citet{Mann:1924} and a quote from  \citet{ThomasMannArchiv}:


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image: Partially complete bibliography and citations]

Comment: Fixing the missing references was indeed a no-no. Also switching from `@webpage` to `@online` was good. In the meantime I read all the relevant documentations and learned quite a bit about (Bib)LaTeX in the last days. Thanks for the pointer.